# Facet API - All available Facets in one Block or on one Page

Tags: views, search

I need to create a page where all values of all fields of a content type are listed. All of these fields are list/text - fields. Behind these listed items I need to print a counter, that counts how many nodes have a certain value. Preferably I would love to do that with views, using aggregation seems not to work and even if it would performance would be the next problem. Trying to use other base-tables playing around with data-module but until now best I could find was https://www.drupal.org/project/searchapimultiaggregate.

For background: Intention is to get some kind of result-summary of statistical data. I know modules like quiz, webform, entityform or even the limequery integration which would perfectly do what is needed, but mainly because all data is already in the nodes, this seems no way to go.